# TF401159 error installing TFS 2013 on a SQL server 2014

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I installed Team Foundation Server 2013 on our machine and we also have SQL Server 2014 Express on that same machine. When I try to configure TFS to connect to the SQL Server 2014, I get error below

It says TFS requires SQL Server 2012 SP1 or higher, which is true in my case since I have SQL Server 2014. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this and a possible way of fixing it?

Comment: you said you have SQL EXPRESS. maybe TFS does not work on EXPRESS edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS 2013 RTM and Update 1 don't support SQL 2014. Support was added in TFS 2013 Update 2.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements

Comment: I updated TFS 2013 to Update 5. Error is gone now. Thank you!